# Кликабельная картинка на ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net

Надо сделать картинку, при клике на которую, пользователь переходил на нужную страницу .aspx другого контролёра.
Вот пример рабочей ссылки средствами ASP:

> <%: Html.ActionLink("Вернуться на
> главную","Index","Home") %>

Как сделать тоже самое, но чтобы в качестве ссылки был не текст, а картинка?
Через свойства картинки установить не получается, т.к. если идёт ссылка на aspx страницу, то разметка сервером не генерируется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("ActionName") %>">
    <img src"/images/image.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Такая проблема решается обычно написанием собственного html-хэлпера (через extension method). Для рисунка-ссылки будет выглядеть примерно так:

Код С#:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkImage(this HtmlHelper helper,
        string src, string url, string cssClass, string title = "")
    {
        var href = new TagBuilder("a");
        href.MergeAttribute("href", url);
        href.MergeAttribute("title", title);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
            href.AddCssClass(cssClass);

        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.MergeAttribute("src", src);
        img.MergeAttribute("alt", title);

        href.InnerHtml = img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(href.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

В коде страницы тогда будете писать:

@Html.ActionLinkImage(параметры) (или ASPX разметка вместо Razor)

Код перепроверьте т.к. не тестировал.

Решение **null** тоже вполне подходит.

Comment: А без написания хелпера никак? Ну просто писать целый хелпер ради одной несложной процедуры, которую легко можно сделать в обычном  HTML...

Comment: Тогда так как написал null.

Comment: Да, как раз проверил. Там явно проще, но и Вам большое спасибо!